# Geodesics: "Transporting tangent vectors in parallel" vs. "Preserving the tangent vector under parallel transport"

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology, geodesic

Wikipedia states:
["*[...] More generally, in the presence of an affine connection, a **geodesic** is defined to be a curve whose tangent vectors remain parallel if they are transported along it.*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic)

Does this characterization apply to solutions $\gamma[ \, t \, ]$ of
$$ \nabla_{\dot \gamma} \! \left[ \, \frac{\dot \gamma}{\|\dot \gamma\|} \, \right] = 0 \tag{1} $$
?

Wikipedia continues:
["*A **geodesic** on a smooth manifold $M$ with an affine connection $\nabla$ is defined as a curve $\gamma[ \, t \, ]$ such that parallel transport along the curve preserves the tangent vector to the curve, so*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic#Affine_geodesics)
$$ \nabla_{\dot \gamma}[ \, \dot \gamma \, ] = 0 \tag{2}$$

Is there additional terminology available for distinguishing between solutions of eq. (1) and solutions of eq. (2) ?

Comment: The difference between the two definitions seems to be whether one assumes the curve to be parametrized by arclength, ie $||\dot{\gamma}||=const$. This should be an a priori assumption so it's a matter of convention whether one makes this assumption or not. The actual definitions should be the same.

Comment: @quarague: "_The difference between the two definitions seems to be whether one assumes [...] $\|\dot \gamma\| = const.$_" -- All solutions of (1) that also satisfy your assumption ("affine parametrization"?) are also solutions of (2); right. (The two definitions, however, remain as they were.) "_[...] a matter of convention whether one makes this assumption_" -- Well, at least such a convention doesn't seem part of the [definition of a "curve"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve). (Perhaps it goes with defining ["affine connection"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_connection) ?? ...)